# Material Button disabledColor not showing entered color in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to display different color when Material button is disabled.
I'm adding property disabledColor and disabledTextColor.
However, disabledTextColor showing exact color entered but disabledColor not showing any color.

Here is my code

disabledColor:Colors.grey, //not working for background color of button
disabledTextColor:Colors.black, // working for text color of button

```
MaterialButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  disabledElevation: 1,
  disabledColor: Colors.black45,
  disabledTextColor: Colors.white70,
  color:Colors.indigo,
  textColor: Colors.white,
  child: Text("Verify",style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 18.0,
  ),),
  onPressed: null,
),
```

I expect the output should display grey as background color and black as text color.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like there is a bug on `MaterialButton` widget, the `disabledColor` variable is not being used, try using `RawMaterialButton`.

```
bool enabled = false;
...
   

RawMaterialButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  disabledElevation: 1,
  fillColor: enabled ? Colors.indigo : Colors.black45,
  textStyle: TextStyle(color: enabled ? Colors.white : Colors.white70),
    child: Text(
      "Verify",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18.0,
      ),
    ),
  onPressed: enabled ? () {} : null,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this scheme

```
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        iconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
            return Colors.green;
          }
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
            return Colors.red;
          }
          return Colors.green;
        }
        ),
      )
```